# Group by users based on cumulative summation using laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have a `MySQL table` called `points` with `4 columns (id, user_id, point, date)`. And, let's consider these dummy rows for better understanding.

| id | user_id | point | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2000-01-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 2000-01-01 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 2000-01-01 |
| 5 | 1 | 6 | 2000-01-02 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 2000-01-02 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 | 2000-01-03 |
| 8 | 2 | 6 | 2000-01-03 |
| 9 | 1 | 1 | 2000-01-04 |
| 10 | 1 | 9 | 2000-01-04 |
| 11 | 2 | 6 | 2000-01-04 |
| 12 | 1 | 7 | 2000-01-05 |
| 13 | 2 | 4 | 2000-01-05 |
| 14 | 1 | 1 | 2000-01-06 |
| 15 | 2 | 6 | 2000-01-06 |

I have two variables `consecutive_days_to_achieve_reward=2` and `per_day_min_points_to_achieve_reward=5`. Now, I want to know `how many times` the users have passed this specific requirement.

So, the result for the above table would be:

| user_id | times |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 `2000-01-01 - 2000-01-02` `2000-01-04 - 2000-01-05` |
| 2 | 1 `2000-01-03 - 2000-01-04` |

I am getting no clue how to solve `MySQL problems with laravel eloquent` dealing with `cumulative summation`. Could someone assist me?

Comment: Retrieve the data for a user and loop through it in PHP. I dont know if there is a pure SQL way to achieve this.

Comment: Hmm, this could be solved in O(N) complexity. But, let's see if someone mentions a MySQL way.

Comment: The consecutive days element is a typical [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem which has been asked lots of times on here. Would 25 points (5 per day) over five consecutive days be counted as 1 or 2?

Comment: Will  be counted as 2 `floor(5 /2)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I understand entirely.  The query below does calculate the days that satisfy that requirement, but I am not sure what you are wanting for 'times' value ?  It sounds like you want the number of groups of 2 or more days and not the absolute number of days there, although you could probably modify the query a bit to get that.

As for Laravel eloquent or the Query Builder you should be able to translate a working query to that format, but if you are not too familiar with Laravel I would get a working MySQL query first.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS times_passed_requirement,
       GROUP_CONCAT(date ORDER BY date) AS satisfied_dates
FROM (
    SELECT t1.user_id, t1.date,
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                    SELECT user_id, date, SUM(point) AS total_points
                    FROM points
                    GROUP BY user_id, date
                ) AS t2
                WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                    AND (t2.date = DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR t2.date = DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                    AND t2.total_points >= 5
            ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS requirement_passed
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, date, SUM(point) AS total_points
        FROM points
        GROUP BY user_id, date
    ) AS t1
    WHERE t1.total_points >= 5
) AS subquery
WHERE requirement_passed = 1
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I at least ran your data through and it seems to give the correct result.

```
user_id passed dates
1      4       2000-01-01,2000-01-02,2000-01-04,2000-01-05
2      2       2000-01-03,2000-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the following (replacing the user-defined variables with params):

```sql
SET @consecutive_days_to_achieve_reward = 2,
    @per_day_min_points_to_achieve_reward = 5;

WITH t1 (user_id, date, point, grp) AS (
    SELECT user_id, date, SUM(point) point, date - INTERVAL ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date ASC) DAY
    FROM points
    GROUP BY user_id, date
    HAVING point >= @per_day_min_points_to_achieve_reward
),
t2 (user_id, consec, min_date, max_date) AS (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(date) consec, MIN(date), MAX(date)
    FROM t1
    GROUP BY user_id, grp
    HAVING consec >= @consecutive_days_to_achieve_reward
)
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(FLOOR(consec/@consecutive_days_to_achieve_reward)) times,
    GROUP_CONCAT(min_date, ' - ', max_date SEPARATOR ', ') date_ranges
FROM t2
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Output:

| user_id | times | date_ranges |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2000-01-01 - 2000-01-02, 2000-01-04 - 2000-01-05 |
| 2 | 1 | 2000-01-03 - 2000-01-04 |

The first CTE produces the following output, based on your sample data (**rn** added to aid understanding):

| user_id | date | point | rn | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 | 5 | 1 | 1999-12-31 |
| 1 | 2000-01-02 | 6 | 2 | 1999-12-31 |
| 1 | 2000-01-04 | 10 | 3 | 2000-01-01 |
| 1 | 2000-01-05 | 7 | 4 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-01-01 | 6 | 1 | 1999-12-31 |
| 2 | 2000-01-03 | 6 | 2 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-01-04 | 6 | 3 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-01-06 | 6 | 4 | 2000-01-02 |

The second CTE outputs:

| user_id | consec | min_date | max_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2000-01-01 | 2000-01-02 |
| 1 | 2 | 2000-01-04 | 2000-01-05 |
| 2 | 2 | 2000-01-03 | 2000-01-04 |

Although the above can be built up using Laravel's Query Builder, I would probably pass the parameterized query to `DB::select()`.